# Mail configuration Limesurvey on EC2

Tags: smtp, limesurvey

I tried to configure SMTP setting on LimeSurvey on EC2 cloud. My setting was Gmail setting. I got a message from Gmail stating someone is attempting to logon to my account from USA. I was then asked to confirm that it was me. I did it. But, Sending mail from Limesurvey does not work. I would like to know how to configure SMTP setting on Limesurvey on EC2 cloud.

Comment: Solved by following https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home#smtp-settings